# Get password from sqlite3 database

Tags: javascript, sql

I have problems when i try to retrieve the password that match the username which has been typed in(username is socket.username). i can get the hashedpassword, but when i try to console.log(getpassword) it just returns: SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = "hej123" as a string. I want to get the password that match the typed in username from the database, and when they login it should check both passwords are same.
Sql query shall take the password from the database
Please help:)

```
socket.on('existing user', function (username, password) {
    // we store the username in the socket session for this client
    socket.username = validator.escape(username);
    socket.password = validator.escape(password);
       
    const salt = 'Some salt for the hash';
  
   // Hash the salt and password with 1000 iterations, 64 length and sha512 digest 
   const hashedPassword = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(socket.password, salt, 1000, 64, 'sha512').toString('hex');

   
    db.serialize(function() {
      
      // console.log('checking if user exists');
      var getPassword = `SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = "${socket.username}"`
      db.get(getPassword, function() {
        console.log(hashedPassword)

        if (getPassword === hashedPassword) {
          console.log("virker")
        }
          else(console.log("ik godt"))
        
      })
```

Comment: A) You're injecting your SQL data values, which is super bad, especially if this is exposed to real users. Use placeholders, like `WHERE username=?` B) You're using SHA512 for passwords, which is far from ideal. Just [use `bcrypt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt).

Comment: You should also look at using `async` and `await` as this callback driven code was proven to be a bad idea over 10 years ago. At *least* use Promises, and better, use `await` which makes your code way easier to structure and follow.

Comment: *"but when i try to console.log(getpassword)"* - The code isn't doing that, but even if it did that value is exactly the string you claim to observe, so it's not clear to me what the problem is.  What isn't working as expected here?